# Dependency error while installing the gem "joyride-rails"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, haml, zurb-joyride

My rails version is `3.2.12`.

I am trying to implement gem `"joyride-rails", "~> 0.0.14"` in my application, but it clashes with some of my other gems. Already in my Gemfile:

```
gem "haml-rails", ">= 0.4"
gem 'activeadmin-mongoid', github: 'elia/activeadmin-mongoid', branch: 'active-admin-spec-suite'
```

When I run the bundle command, I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "haml":
  In Gemfile:
    joyride-rails (~> 0.0.14) ruby depends on
      haml (~> 3.1) ruby

    haml-rails (>= 0.4) ruby depends on
      haml (4.0.3)
```

So, if I add the gem `"haml", "~> 4.0.3"` the new bundle clash is:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bourbon":
  In Gemfile:
    joyride-rails (~> 0.0.14) ruby depends on
      bourbon (~> 2.0) ruby

    activeadmin-mongoid (>= 0) ruby depends on
      bourbon (3.1.8)
```

And if I then add the gem `"bourbon", "~> 3.1.8"` I get this new clash:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bourbon":
  In Gemfile:
    joyride-rails (~> 0.0.14) ruby depends on
      bourbon (~> 2.0) ruby

    bourbon (3.1.8)
```

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Github Issue](https://github.com/TrueNorth/joyride-rails/issues/1)

The gem currently can't be used with the latest version of haml. (c)

I think, u can downgrade your haml version, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have gotten it to work with these additions to my gemfile. Do you see any issues here? If so, please update the answer accordingly.

    gem "haml", "3.1.4"
    gem "joyride-rails"
    gem "bourbon", "~> 2.0"

Comment: Hmm, update on the above. Even though the bundle didn't object, the application was unable to require the js and the css files. I think I'll just give up and find another solution.