# Rails gem for adding an on site tutorial supported for rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to add an on boarding tutorial to my site. I've installed the joyride-rails gem and am getting this error when running bundle install.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
In Gemfile:
joyride-rails (~> 0.0.14) ruby depends on
rails (~> 3.1) ruby

rails (4.1.6)
```

I've done some research and found this answer [Dependency error while installing the gem "joyride-rails"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18867225/dependency-error-while-installing-the-gem-joyride-rails)

And this answer [Simple Javascript Joyride plugin in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843616/simple-javascript-joyride-plugin-in-rails)

The problem is I think that the joyride gem just isn't compatible with rails 4 and when I down grade to 3.1 a bunch of my other gems are in conflict. I delte the gemfile.lock and run bundle install and get this error.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
 In Gemfile:
  coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
  railties (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0.beta) ruby

rails (= 3.1) ruby depends on
  railties (3.1.0)
```

Any suggestions as to how I can implement this gem? Or do you know of another Gem that will accomplish the same goal?

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, Joyride is part of the ZURB Fountation, why not use it?

Comment: I found this link about foundation. http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/rails.html I don't have experience using this. Is it similar to a bootstrap framework? My site is built with twitter bootsrap. Can I integrate foundation anyway? EDIT: I commented out my joyride-rails gem and added gem 'compass-rails' # you need this or you get an err
gem 'zurb-foundation', '~> 4.0.0' becasue I already had the other dependancies. Anything Else I should think of?

Comment: I ended up not adding foundation as it's an entire framework. Any other suggestions?